# Chilkat connection exception in FTP2 in c#

Tags: c#, chilkat

I am getting the following message in the chilkat exception

```
  calling ConnectSocket2
    IPV6 enabled connect with NO heartbeat.
    Cannot connect, hostname is zero length
    ConnectFailReason: 1
    Failed to connect to FTP server.
    Failed.   --ConnectOnly_Ftp2
--ChilkatLog
```

I am trying to connect to FTP server using chilkat's Ftp2 class(using c#), using Connect method.

Following is my class which I am using to connect with the FTP2

```
   public class FTPClient
   {        
    private Ftp2 m_FtpInfo;

    const int FTP_DEFAULT_PORT = 21;

    public FTPClient()
    {
        m_FtpInfo = null;
    }

    public FTPClient(string userName, string password, string hostName, int port)
    {
        m_FtpInfo = new Ftp2();
        m_FtpInfo.Account = userName;
        m_FtpInfo.ClientIpAddress = hostName;
        m_FtpInfo.Password = password;
        //m_FtpInfo.Port = port;
    }

    public Ftp2 FTPInfo
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_FtpInfo == null)
                m_FtpInfo = new Ftp2();
            return m_FtpInfo;
        }
        set { m_FtpInfo = value; }
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            if (m_FtpInfo == null)
            {
                m_FtpInfo = new Ftp2();
            }

            AppConfiguration appConfiguration = AppConfiguration.Instance;
            /*
             * Steps to connect to FTP site using Chilkat
             * 1. Unlock the component by passing the code provided by Chilkat
             * 2. Connect to the Site by specifying the hostname and port
             */

            // Unlock the component.
            if (!m_FtpInfo.UnlockComponent("AnythingWorksFor30DayTrial"))
            {
                throw new FTPConnectionExceptions(CommunicationError.UnlockFailed, m_FtpInfo.LastErrorText);
            }


            // Connect to the FTP server. (use a domain name or IP address)            
            if (!m_FtpInfo.Connect())
            {
                throw new FTPConnectionExceptions(CommunicationError.ConnectionFailed, m_FtpInfo.LastErrorText);
            }
        }
    }

    public void DisposeConnection()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            if (m_FtpInfo == null) return;

            if (m_FtpInfo.IsConnected)
                m_FtpInfo.Disconnect();

            m_FtpInfo = null;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please tell where am I going wrong?

Comment: The error `Cannot connect, hostname is zero length` could mean you forgot to set destination server. Can you provide some code (create an instance, setting properties, calling connect, etc.)?

Comment: I have edited my post to give the class details for connecting with FTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `m_FtpInfo.ClientIpAddress = hostName;` isn't required. The actual host to connect to isn't set.

**Edit:**

The Chilkat example page sets the hostname like this:

```
ftp.Hostname = "ftp.chilkatsoft.com";
```

So instead of setting ClientIpAddress (the local PC's ip), use Hostname.

**Edit 2:**

Try this:

```
public FTPClient(string userName, string password, string hostName, int port)
{
    m_FtpInfo = new Ftp2();
    m_FtpInfo.Account = userName;
    m_FtpInfo.Hostname = hostName;
    m_FtpInfo.Password = password;
    //m_FtpInfo.Port = port;
}
```